# Carousel cannot be used as JSX component problem

Tags: react-native, web-scraping, jsx, carousel, react-responsive-carousel

I was creating a price tracker for my web scrapping project and the next step was to add a carousel when I added it , shows the following error
'Carousel' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'typeof Carousel' is not a valid JSX element type. Types of construct signatures are incompatible. Type 'new (props: CarouselProps) => Carousel' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>'. Type 'Carousel' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<any, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.ts(2786)

Iam new so I don't want anything to destroy
[while adding this is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aWvJ.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiRYf.png)

I saw through various solution in the internet but they didn't work so I am asking help for someone who can fi this error